# Default hash values in Ruby (Rubykoans.com -> about_hashes.rb)

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm going through about_hashes.rb from [RubyKoans](http://rubykoans.com/). 1 exercise got me puzzled:

```
 def test_default_value
    hash1 = Hash.new
    hash1[:one] = 1

    assert_equal 1, hash1[:one] #ok
    assert_equal nil, hash1[:two] #ok

    hash2 = Hash.new("dos")
    hash2[:one] = 1

    assert_equal 1, hash2[:one] #ok
    assert_equal "dos", hash2[:two] #hm?
  end
```

My guess is that Hash.new("dos") makes "dos" the default answer for all non-existent keys. Am I right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you are right, looks like there is a mistake in ruby koans, `hash2[:two]` will return `"dos"`

Take a look at [Hash.new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-c-new) method documentation

> new → new_hash
>   **new(obj)** → new_hash
>   new {|hash, key| block } → new_hash
>
> Returns a new, empty hash. If this hash is subsequently accessed by a
>   key that doesn’t correspond to a hash entry, the value returned
>   depends on the style of new used to create the hash. In the first
>   form, the access returns nil. **If obj is specified, this single object
>   will be used for all default values**. If a block is specified, it will
>   be called with the hash object and the key, and should return the
>   default value. It is the block’s responsibility to store the value in
>   the hash if required.

*Sidenote*: You can confirm your expectations in such cases by running the actual code or by executing couple of lines in [irb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Ruby_Shell) or [pry](http://pry.github.com/) (I recommend pry).

Answer (score 4):

The original of the koan is:

```
def test_default_value
  hash1 = Hash.new
  hash1[:one] = 1

  assert_equal __, hash1[:one]
  assert_equal __, hash1[:two]

  hash2 = Hash.new("dos")
  hash2[:one] = 1

  assert_equal __, hash2[:one]
  assert_equal __, hash2[:two]
end
```

The error is not in the koan, but in the assertion you've completed:

```
assert_equal nil, hash2[:two] #hm?
```

...should be

```
assert_equal "dos", hash2[:two] #hm?
```